# Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've seen several websites ([like this one](http://www.labnol.org/software/deobfuscate-javascript/19815/) and [this one](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/06/de-obfuscating-javascript-code-in.html)) that says the Google Chrome Web Browser has a javascript de-obfuscator built into the developer tools. I can not seem to find this though. Can someone please point me in the right direction of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe they are referring to the `{}` button on the "Sources" tab, or in older versions of Chrome, the "Scripts" tab.

Comment: Yes, I found it. Apparently its called "Pretty Print" now and it can be access through the {} button, as you suggested. Thanks mikez302